# The command npx create-react-app doesn't work for me

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

when i try to create a new react project with npx it doesn't create all files like src files and gitgnore(like in [the screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zToOb.png))
'''

```
C:\Users\ANAS\Desktop>npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ANAS\Desktop\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1392 packages in 20s

212 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Comment: What's the issue specifically? That output looks quite standard and doesn't seem to give any information go on.

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's nothing here anyone could use to help.

Comment: You show the structure of `my-app` but your command creates an app named `my-app2`, are you just looking in the wrong folder?

Comment: plz answer my quetion , cause i need it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clair, but my be you have installed create-react-app globaly.
Try to remove it

```
Run npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then use this command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't works, but ty.